# Who's Brook supposed to be in this image?

Tags: one-piece

In this image, we can see:

- Luffy as Captain America
- Robin as Agent Maria Hill
- Frankie as Iron Man
- Nami as Black Widow
- Chopper as Hulk
- Sanji as Nick Fury
- Zoro as Thor
- Usopp as Hawkeye

But, I don't know who Brook should be...

[image: Avengers One piece]

Comment: Coulson, because they're both dead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found out who he should be!

It's Agent Phillip "**Phil**" **Coulson** being pierced by Loki

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vK0FPtYTvY#t=16